# Cookie Response Statuscode gets overwritten

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session, cookies, http-status-codes

We are developing a web based application with Asp.Net MVC (and will somewhen upgrade/migrate to Core 2.0) in which the session of a user might runs out. Now we want to catch that, if the user is still signed in in a browser tab, with the expired session and does something though an ajax call (clicks on smth. that triggers anything). Then, we can catch the returned statuscode of the call in ajaxComplete like so

```
$(() => {
$(document).ajaxComplete((e, xhr, settings) => {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status === 401) {
                var returnUrl = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
                window.location.href = `/Account/Login?returnUrl=${returnUrl}`;
            }
}
```

We use cookie based authentication which is declared somewhat like this in the Startup:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            options =>
                {   
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "OurMiddlewareInstance";
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied/");
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieHttpOnly = false;
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                            {
                                var isAjax = ctx.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
                                if (isAjax)
                                {
                                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                                }
                                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                    };
                    if (!_isDevelopment)
                    {
                        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieDomain = "localhost";
                    }
                })
                // ... and some other stuff
```

The thing now is, if i don't set the cookieDomain like

```
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieDomain = "localhost";
```

ajaxCalls will receive a 401 if they do a request with an expired session. But with it being set, i only receive a 404. As you can see, i tried adding an event handler on *OnRedirectToLogin*, which sets the Statuscode. Still, i will receive a 404 at the client/browser.

I don't know where this statuscode that i am setting gets overwritten or why i experience said behaviour. If anyone could say why this happens, how the cookie domain has something to do with it, or at least could point me in the right direction, it'll be much appreaciated.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest packages. I ran your code and I could not recreate your error

Comment: Just make sure you have your middleware set up properly. It should be static files first --> then authentication -->  the rest of your middleware. If you have authentication after something, it could cause weird results

Comment: @UmarKarimabadi I will look into that as soon as I can. As it is, the priority of this problem was just lowered and something else came up. Please bear with me if it takes a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem. It wasn't that the domain had much to do with it (somewhat yes, but it was not the root of the poblem).

In our live enviroment for this project, we obviously don't want to display "native" errorpages or exception messages. Therefore some Handlers were added like so

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/MyController/Error");
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/MyController/Error_{0}");
```

which display the corresponing page if an error or something else happens. Now, MyController didn't have a Method for the 401 Error, for which he then returned the 404 Error in the end.